# Xcode 6 Landscape Orientation issue

Tags: xcode6

I am trying to update my project to iOS 8.0. But i am getting landscape orientation problem in my app. Searched for more options but couldnt found any.

[Environment]
Xcode 6.1 
simulator: iPad2 
ipad air